# multiple Drilldown in Highcharts using values from database in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, highcharts

I have the following tables in my database

> table1 animals-->
>
> columns [name,count]
>
> ```
> [cat,4] 
> [dog,2]
> [cow,1]
> ```
>
> table2 cars--->
>
> columns [name,count]
>
> ```
>  [toyota,4]
>  [opel,2]
> ```
>
> table3 toyota-->
>
> ```
> columns [name,count]
>
> [liva,2]
> [etios,2]
> ```

I want to fetch the data from data base and dynamically create multiple drill down charts using high-charts. eg:cars-->toyota-->etios .....etc 
the following code with static data works fine.how to pass dynamic values using Ruby?

```
series: [{
            name: 'Things',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Animals',
                y: 3,
                drilldown: 'animals'
            },  {
                name: 'Cars',
                y: 2,
                drilldown: 'cars'
            }]
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                id: 'animals',
                data: [
                    ['Cats', 4],
                    ['Dogs', 2],
                    ['Cows', 1]

                ]
            },  {
                id: 'cars',
                data: [
                    {
                name: 'Toyota',
                y: 4,
                drilldown: 'Toyota'
            },
                ]
            }, {
                id: 'Toyota',
                data: [
                    ['Etios', 2],
                    ['Liva', 2]
                ]
            }]
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do many things for that

1) First use group_by method like

```
group =@animals.group_by(&:name)

hash = group.values
```

after that

```
2)  value = hash.collect(&:first)  
3) then use value.map for getting   
4) Use Hash.new {|h,k| [k, variable.count(k)] }
```

after that ,  as you want just change or add some more steps like count , uniq, or collect 
at last my highcharts script is ,this is my code , you can customized as you need ...

```
series: [{
type: 'pie',
name: 'Country Visits',
data: [
<% for index in 0 ... @country_name.size%>
<% if index == 0 %>
 ['<%= @country_name[index ] %>', <%= @country_name_visits[index]%>]
 <% else %>
 ,['<%= @country_name[index ] %>', <%= @country_name_visits[index]%>]
<% end %> 
<% end %>
]
}]
```

Comment: i think u ddint get wat i exactly needed.multiple drilldown is wat i required.if we click 'cars' it wil drill down and show different car vendores name and their count (eg:[toyota,4] [opel,2]).again if we click on any car vendor ,suppose 'toyota',it must further drill down and give different toyota cars names and their count.(eg:['Etios', 2],['Liva', 2])

Comment: I think for that, you have to use dropdown , so that if you click on "cars" in your highcharts script, your instance varible will change to the cars value varibles. , i think there is not only highcharts , you also have to use ajax  for multiple dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

```
 series: [{
        name: 'Things',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [<%@comp.each do |com|%>
                  { name:'<%=com.name%>',
                    y: <%=com.count%>,
                    drilldown: '<%= com.name%>'
                  },
                      <%end%>
                      ]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [ <%@car.each do |qq|%>
                  {
                  id: '<%=qq.name%>',

                  data: [
                  <%@cars.each do |q|%>
                     <% if q.name == qq.name  %>
                     {
                        name:'<%=q.carvendor%>',
                      y: <%=q.count%>,
                      drilldown: '<%= q.carvendor%>'         
                    },
                    <%end%>
                     <%end%> 
                       ]
                  },
                  <%end%>

                ]
                 }
```